# Is there any way, how to set retry to liveSync, if liveSync fail?

Tags: wso2, high-availability, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

We have following liveSync configurations

[image]

If we have heartbeatMaxRetry set to 10. After 10 unsuccessful attempts liveSync fails. Is there any way how to run liveSync again after fail?
when liveSync fails, we have two active nodes in HA cluster as you can see on screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A node getting resolved as an active node does not depend on the liveSync configuration. liveSync configuration is a strategy used to sync the state of Siddhi Applications between active and passive node.
Can you add in the relevant configurations of both nodes to get a better idea of the deployment?